# Почему фильтр не выводит данные по дням?

Tags: php

Приветствую.

Сижу делаю фильтр, начал тестировать выяснилось что конструкция

$filtr_date = 'and (datetime BETWEEN "'.$date_go.'" and "'.$date_to.'")';

при параметрах например: с 2015-04-19 по 2015-04-19

не выводит запись в базе, где дата 2015-04-19, если ставишь промежуток допустим с 2015-04-18 по 2015-04-19, тогда выводит запись с датой 2015-04-19

**Почему?**

P.S.: кто-нибудь делал фильтры по дате есть готовые решения?  например по стандартным параметрам сегодня, вчера, неделя, месяц, год, все время, период

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что даты стравниваются как строки.
И потому что сравнивать надо *подобные* величины, а не надеяться, что БД сконвертирует их за тебя сама.

В поле типа datetime **не бывает** записей с датой вида `2015-04-19`, а бывают только с датой и временем, `2015-04-19 10:10:10`. Такая строка всегда будет больше, чем наибольшее значение заданного только датой диапазона, и под условие не попадёт.

Если нужно хранить только дату, то не нужно использовать тип datetime.

Чтобы искать по datetime, надо задавать условия так же в формате datetime

```
BETWEEN '2015-04-19 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-19 23:59:59'
```

найдет все записи, в которых дата равна 2015-04-19

Comment: спасибо большое я не знал этого, но предполагал.